# Through signing process with HSM Luna, What device perform the signing?

Tags: java, hsm, pkcs11

I'v succesfully configure and test character String signin usign Java and HSM Luna SA through PKCS11. My question is, In wich processor cryptographic operations are perform?

In wich way HSM Luna could speed up masive signing.